# Column showing revenue increasing cumulatively, then only repeats the max value after a certain date

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm creating a dashboard that, among other things, shows how much revenue a rep generated in their first month of joining the company.

This is going to be based off a table I'm creating with SQL. The simplest version of this table will be:

date (which will be every day of the week), rep name, revenue generated from when they joined.

This will be increasing cumulatively (so when you select a date in the dashboard, you see the total amount generated up until that day).

As we're only interested in revenue generated in the first month, I want my revenue table to be increasing cumulatively up until we get to 1 month from start date, then, whatever that max number is, to just be repeated all the way down my column. So after the first month, any date you select in the dashboard, you will still only see the 1 month number. I want to do it this way as I think it'll be easier to do in SQL, and not my dashboard tool, as then I have to bring through more data and run further calculations there too.

To do this, I first created a sub query:

```
(SELECT date, rep name, sum(revenue) as revenue
FROM rev Group BY 1,2) as a
```

So this gives me revenue generated on every single day for the rep.

I'm then querying this sub query, whilst joining to a table giving me start date. So my new query starts like this:

```
SELECT a.date, a.rep name,

SUM(CASE WHEN (a.date- b.join_date < 1 month) then sum(a.revenue)
```

I'm now stuck on the ELSE part. Do I want to partition here?

My thoughts are something like:

```
ELSE sum(revenue) partition over(rep name, add_months(join_date, 1) order by date asc)
```

But I don't think that makes a lot of sense?

Essentially, what I want to see as final output is this. In order to keep the table short, I will assume I want revenue in the first week of them joining (not month like I actually want):

[image]

In this example, I am pretending the rep started generating money on the first day of them joining, which is the 2020-02-19. What I have in the first three columns is the current output of my sub query (the individual amounts they generated on each day). I want to aggregate that up to another query, which gives me the 4th column. I hope this makes things a little clearer!

Comment: Your first subquery is broken.  You have aggregation functions mixed with unaggregated columns and no group by.  Sample data and desired results are very helpful.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Teradata does not require a group by clause - it treats all non-aggregations as fields in a group by. +1 on requests for data and results.

Comment: @michael . . . Interesting.  The Teradata documentation explicitly states:  "Nonaggregated variables in SELECT, ORDER BY, and HAVING need to appear in the group by list." (https://docs.teradata.com/reader/huc7AEHyHSROUkrYABqNIg/onPtKrXHBVluNHBmGQrEAA).  Do you have a reference that the clause is optional in this case?

Comment: Hey @GordonLinoff thanks for your reply. That was just me being lazy and not writing things properly on here, I will edit my post to write my query properly and add some sample data/output

Comment: @GordonLinoff Apologies - I had my engines confused. I remembered Teradata had some unique feature with GROUP BY and thought it was that. Upon looking at the docs, it's the ordinal GROUP BY syntax (e.g., GROUP BY 1,2,3)

Comment: Hey guys, I have added a sample output which hopefully helps explain the issue a little more!

Comment: Seems like you just want something like `SUM(CASE WHEN a.date > add_months(b.join_date, 1) then a.revenue END) over (partition by a.rep_name order by a.date)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Fred commented, a conditional agregation in a running total should be what you want:

```
SELECT date, rep_name, sum(revenue) as revenue
  ,sum(CASE WHEN a.date <= add_months(b.join_date, 1) then sum(revenue) END) 
   over (partition by rep_name
         order by date
         rows unbounded preceding) as monthly_rev
FROM rev as a
join ...
Group BY 1,2
```

Comment: Yes, I reversed the comparison in the WHEN. Thanks for catching it.